# PDO errorinfo not returns info

Tags: php, pdo

I have code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare(" bla bla ");
$stmt->execute();
print_r($db->errorInfo());
```

This returns: `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

Why not returned error info ?

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());`?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't but Exceptions are better anyway. [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/285587)

Answer (score 6):

The following reports the error correctly:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

if (($stmt = $dbh->prepare(" bla bla ")) === false) {
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}

if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

**Note** in the above that parse errors caused during `prepare()` are reported against `$dbh`.  Whereas even if the `prepare()` succeeds, then `execute()` may cause an error, but that error is reported against `$stmt`.

In the test above, I got the error report immediately after the `prepare()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
           check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
           syntax to use near 'bla bla' at line 1
)
```

**But this behavior changes if you use emulated prepares.**

When you enable that attribute, the `prepare()` is virtually a no-op.  It just saves the query string in the $stmt, and then the actual prepare of the statement is delayed until you call `execute()`.  So the error, if any, is reported against `$stmt` whether it happens at prepare time or at execute time.

I tested changing the error-reporting line as follows:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);

// prepare won't report SQL errors, it's virtually a no-op.
if (($stmt = $dbh->prepare(" bla bla ")) === false) {
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}

// execute will report errors of parsing or execution.
if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

In this case, no error was reported at `prepare()`, and but I got the same error as above at `execute()`.  Again, you must examine `$stmt` to get the error after `execute()`.

Answer (score -2):

SQLSTATE 00000 means "Success". Per the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/pdo.errorInfo):

> If the SQLSTATE error code is not set or there is no driver-specific error, the elements following element 0 will be set to NULL.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.